# Android app Signup/login not working in the play store

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, firebase-authentication

I uploaded an Android app to the play store, but I'm unable to log in or register in that app. Everything is working fine when using a virtual device or by connecting the phone using the USB wire.

When a user tries to sign up nothing happens (even on `Firebase` database). And when a user that is already registered tries to login, the page just refreshes again and the user cannot login.

Comment: i think its because of your google play signing `SHA-1` key is not registered in `firebase` console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you could do is , copy the `SHA1` key from google play console, its in the **App Signing** tab

[image]

and then goto `firebase` console , select app goto settings then add new `fingerprint`.

[image]

After this download `google-services.json` file update the application. or the other way around is to goto [Google Api Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and then create credentials.

Hope this helps

Comment: In my "App Singing" tab, there is no place for SHA1 key.                                           https://imgur.com/a/u4QOf

Comment: well its not the complete picture , is there any option of enroll etc?

Comment: again its not the complete picture , if there's an option of enrol do it

Comment: sorry, there is on the bottom but it is disabled for me   https://imgur.com/a/f6rso

Comment: have you uploaded the apk? its disabled when apk is not uploaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166693/discussion-between-mohan-adhikari-and-abdul-kawee).